# Angular 2 Custom Pipe

Tags: angular

I'm following the turorial of John Lindquist about Angular 2 on egghead.com and after doing exactly the same thing as him I don't have the same result.

It's about the course 17.

I have a custom filter which works perfectly :

started-pipe.ts

```
import {Pipe} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: "started"
})

export class StartedPipe{
    transform(value, [status]){
        return value.filter((item)=> item.status === "started");
    }
}
```

todo-list.ts

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {TodoService} from "./todo-service";
import {TodoItemRenderer} from "./todo-item-renderer";
import {StartedPipe} from './started-pipe';

@Component({
    selector: 'todo-list',
    pipes: [StartedPipe],
    directives: [TodoItemRenderer],
    template: `
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor="let todo of todoService.todos | started :     'started'">
                    <todo-item-renderer 
                    [todo]="todo"
                    (toggle)="todoService.toggleTodo($event)">
                    </todo-item-renderer>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    `
})

export class TodoList{
    @Input() status;
    constructor(public todoService: TodoService){}
}
```

But when I want to use the array arg of my transform value it does not work anymore :

started-pipe.ts

```
import {Pipe} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: "started"
})

export class StartedPipe{
    transform(value, [status]){
        return value.filter((item)=> item.status === status);
    }
}
```

If you have an idea it's welcomed !

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the syntax a bit:

```
 transform(value, status){ // remove brackets from status
```

Starting with **beta.16** pipe transform signature has been changed from

```
export interface PipeTransform { transform(value: any, args: any[]): any; }
```

to

```
export interface PipeTransform { transform(value: any, ...args: any[]): any; }
```

See also:  https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-1

Comment: Hey buddy :) One question: are you sure this is still the way to do it? It seems I cannot have anymore a pipe property on the component.

Comment: @johnnyfittizio You should declare your pipe within `declarations` array of your module

Comment: But do you mean declarations property of the app.module.ts?

Comment: @johnnyfittizio Exactly

Comment: But if I don't want to make it global. Can I just import it in the component?

Comment: @johnnyfittizio Create feature module for this https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#feature-modules

Comment: Sorry - I really couldn't manage to import a pipe only locally in the component besides using the feature module. I have asked a question specifically about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40977490/angular-2-import-pipe-locally

Comment: @johnnyfittizio https://plnkr.co/edit/8AAWL2KpPbDoDZto9xdF?p=preview You can also take a look at another examples https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/2.0.0-alpha.10/src/lib/button/button.ts#L159-L171