# Angular 2 - Import pipe locally

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe

**THE SITUATION:**

I need to use a pipe in only one component. For this reason i didn't wanted to import it globally but only in the component.

I have tried looking for reference on how to do it but couldn't find it.

This is my attempt:

**THE PIPE:**

when tested globally is working fine

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value, args:string[]) : any 
    {
        let keys = [];      
        for (let key in value) 
        {
            keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
        }
        return keys;
    }
}
```

**THE COMPONENT**:

```
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";

import { KeysPipe } from './keys.pipe';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-attendees',
  templateUrl: 'attendees.html'
})

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ KeysPipe ],
  imports: [ CommonModule ],
  exports: [ KeysPipe ]
})

export class AttendeesPage {

    public attendeeList = [];
    public arrayOfKeys;

    constructor(
        public navCtrl: NavController,
        public navParams: NavParams
    ) {
        this.attendeeList = this.navParams.get('attendeeList');
        this.arrayOfKeys = Object.keys(this.attendeeList);
    }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log('AttendeesPage');
    }
}
```

**THE ERROR:**

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'keys' could not be found
```

[image]

**PLUNKER:**

https://plnkr.co/edit/YJUHmAkhAMNki2i6A9VY?p=preview

**THE QUESTION:**

Do you know what I am doing wrong or if I am missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe reproduce within a Plunkr. I do not see anything weird so far.

Comment: Ok I have added it to the question.

Answer (score 8):

You declared two `NgModules` and your pipe was only declared in the second module. **BUT** your component was declared into the first module. That's why it couldn't find your pipe.

Here's an updated (and working version) of your Plunkr :
https://plnkr.co/edit/P3PmghXAbH6Q2nZh2CXK?p=preview

**EDIT 1 : Comparison**

Here's what you had before (with non relevant code removed) :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ KeysPipe ],
  imports: [ CommonModule ],
  exports: [ KeysPipe ]
})

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <li *ngFor="let attendee of attendeeList | keys">
      {{ attendee.value.name }}
    </li>
  `,
})
export class App {
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And here's the working version :

```
//our root app component
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <li *ngFor="let attendee of attendeeList | keys">
      {{ attendee.value.name }}
    </li>
  `,
})
export class App {
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, CommonModule ],
  declarations: [ App, KeysPipe ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Notice that you have 2 NgModules. I used only one, removed the other and I added the pipe into `declarations`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you mean to delete one ngModule. One is the general one and I cannot delete... And the other is the one that 'should' allow me to import the pipe only locally.

Comment: Btw I am sorry there was a typo in my plunkr.. I fixed it in both - mine and your - so now in your plunkr we can properly see the list

Answer (score 0):

You can define your pipe in the `providers` array in component, than declare it in your `constructor` and finally use it in the component.

```
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";

import { KeysPipe } from './keys.pipe';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-attendees',
  templateUrl: 'attendees.html',
  providers: [ KeysPipe ]
})

@NgModule({
  imports: [ CommonModule ],
})

export class AttendeesPage {

    public attendeeList = [];
    public arrayOfKeys;

    keys;

    constructor(
        public navCtrl: NavController,
        public navParams: NavParams,
        private keysPipe: KeysPipe 
    ) {
        this.attendeeList = this.navParams.get('attendeeList');
        this.arrayOfKeys = Object.keys(this.attendeeList);
        this.keys = this.keysPipe(this.arrayOfKeys, this.attendeeList)
    }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log('AttendeesPage');
    }
}
```